Promise.race not stopping the execution of long running task
Hi in this code block my requirement is to execute the function test() such that it should stop executing ( it was going through an infinite loop and crashing the page) if it takes for than 1 min.
I used promise and timer to solve this issue but here the problem i am facing is timeout function is being called even before executeWithRace was executed and it is not working as expected, How to refactor this code?
async function executeWithRace() {
    const response = await Promise.race([timeoutPromise, testPromise]);
    console.log(response)
}


    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Timed Out');
        }, 60000); // 1 minute timeout
    });
 



  
    const testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
            test(); // Execute the original test function
            resolve("testSuccessfull"); // Resolve if test function completes without error
      
    });

Thanks
I also tried to create functions for both of the promises and passed those functions to promise.race() but here I have faced this situation : only the first mentioned function in promise.race() was being executed and both the functions weren't being executed simultaneously.
---I wanted to know why this issue "only the first mentioned function in promise.race() was being executed and both the functions weren't being executed simultaneously" when functions are passed to promise.race instead of promise objects, I noticed this by adding some debugging console logs.

JS is single threaded so your "infinite loop" function blocks everything else completely. You cannot solve that with async or setTimeout (they are blocked too). You could try a worker and worker.terminate() for scenarios like that.

I am trying to use promise.race for the same reason, to run the timer and the main intended functions simultaneously so that when settimeout responds with  ('Timed Out'); after a minute the promise.race receives that first and stops the other function. Please correct me if i have misunderstanding in the concept of promise.race() .

@SourabhRaja any function doing having calculations blocks JS completely, nothing could help except running it in a separate worker

@SourabhRaja - you have a misunderstanding in how javascript engines work - the infinite loop can't be "tamed" by Promises
